# CSS for uniform form input heights

Tags: html, css

This one always bugs me

**CSS**

```
/* reset */
input,button { 
     margin:0;padding:0;border:0;
     font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit;
     line-height:1em; }

/* apply some style */
input,button { padding:.5em; }
input { background-color:#fff; }
button { background-color:#333; color:#fff; }

/* for display example */
body { padding:3em; font-size:2em; }
div { background-color:#ccc; padding:.5em }
```

**Markup**

```
<div>
   <span><input type="text" value=" the input value "/></span>
   <span><button> A button</button></span>
</div>
```

**So,** 
Given enough width and the span enabling the `inline` display ...

**Why are they different heights?**

The above code is [running here](http://jsfiddle.net/8DkFZ/)

---

**Workarounds** have been along the lines of:

1) *Specify a height* - fine, better if using ems, but really???

2) *Wrap the elements* ( like in the example, div and span ) and style the wrappers ( effectively giving the inputs/buttons some room to differ across browsers)

---

Hoping I have just missed a piece of css on my travels.

Most search finds on this subject point me to the workarounds

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a better fiddle to see the height difference http://jsfiddle.net/8DkFZ/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the  `line-height: 1em` from the button fixes it in Chrome. For Firefox, adding this fixes it:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin-top:0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}
```

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DkFZ/3/) works in Chrome and Firefox.

[Reference](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-buttons)

Comment: ace, this gets me close, (ff still larger ( a smidge ) and actually shows that resets that set line heights are causing problems. but this is dam close and will work in most cases. ace thank you

Comment: Aha, that's good timing , as I you can see, just added this answer in myself! - great, this keeps the answer in both places. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS script called normalize.CSS (would link but on mobile). A more comprehensive version of reset. I would suggest linking to it rather than putting it in each CSS file. Try adding that, I find it gives me consistency.

Link added: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Thanks @indofraisure, I use normalise and resets , if this does it, it is possible something I have something 'unnormalising - **::-moz-focus-inner** from it looks promising , I shall give it some more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving two great answers, it was a combination of [both](http://jsfiddle.net/6xP5j/1/)

1) From **@Aphol** regarding removing  `line-height` or setting `line-height:normal`

2) From **@indofraiser** Using the normalise, which contains the `::-moz-focus-inner`

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The answer is a combination of the two - which works and feels great, as, after setting line-height:normal, there is still a height difference on firefox ( but it is the closest yet ) and the then the `::-moz-focus-inner` mops that up.

**Thanks you two - the final combo of both answers is here -** http://jsfiddle.net/6xP5j/1/

Thanks again, bye bye to the workarounds! Great.

Answer (score 0):

It's because while you've reset common browser defaults such as margin and padding, you've inherited the font-size, and the font size is slightly different on a button than it is for an input field.

If you specify a font-size in your button, input{} style, they'll instantly become exactly the same size.

Also, "em"s are relative, and even though you've set them to zero on the elements, they're still referenced to calculate the relative value the "em" is going to be.

So specify a font size, and don't use ems if you want absolutes and it'll become the same size.

Although the workarounds might be better in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @i-conica. Appreciate the reply. Don't use EMS is a tad hard to accept though and font inherit, does 'inherit' so interested to explore that you say font sizes are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrap clearfix>
   <span class="inputfield"><input type="text" value=" the input value "/></span>
   <span class="btn><button> A button</button></span>
</div>


.wrap{
   width:100%;
}
span.btn{
  width: 40%;
}
span.inputfield{
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-flex;

}
```